# proxy only one user

Tags: proxy

Our club has a account to a webservice what does not allow, that more than one user is logged-in at the same time (we all use the same credentials).

Technically it's possible that 2 users are logged in at once, but the  general terms of the service tells, that we will be terminated, if they notice that.

I am searching for some kind of proxy service in between user and service, that
asures, that only one user connect at the same time.
(best one i can install on a linux server)

can squid do that?